# Squeeze Theorem for Sequences - Is the 1st condition actually necessary?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $ \{a_n\}, \{b_n\} $ and $\{c_n\}$ be sequences $\in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> If $$a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n ~~\forall~~ n$$ and if
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} c_n = L$$
>
> then $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = L$.

Question: How is the first condition necessary for the theorem to be truth?
For example let's say that the first inequality doesn't hold for $n \leq 100$. Therefore it only holds for $n >100$. This fact doesn't seem (to me) to get in the way of the conclusion of the theorem, because what matters for the truth of the theorem is what happens when $ n \longrightarrow \infty .$

Comment: What about finite sequences?

Answer (score 3):

You can get away with a weaker form of the first condition:

> There exists $N$ such that $a_n\le b_n\le c_n$ for all $n\ge N$.

since, as you remark, all that matters is what is true for all large $n$. This isn't much of a concession, though, since if the original condition doesn't hold until $n=N$, you can re-index your sequences to "start" at this value $N$, and then you're back to the original condition starting at $n=1$. (We are relying on the fact that if $\lim x_n$ exists, then for every $K$, the sequence $( x_{n+K})$ has the same limit as $(x_n)$ -- which is the essence of your remark.)

Comment: Exactly. What matters is at infinity, not any arbitrary n.